# keep sequence same for list of items

Tags: c#, oracle11g

In my orders table I have PK `INVOICE ID` for each order item within the invoice 
and a FK `CUSTOMER ID` I want to keep the `CUSTOMER ID` sequence same for same item within below code is doing the job but I just want to know if I am doing it with right way or there is a better way to do it

```
string connstr = "Data Source=JDT; User Id=admin; password=admin;";

string seqcmdtxt = @"SELECT CUSTOMER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL AS CUSTSEQ FROM DUAL";

string insertcmdtxt = @"INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORDER_ID,
                                            CUSTOMER_ID,
                                            PRODUCT_ID,
                                            QUANTITY,
                                            UNIT_PRICE,
                                            ORDER_STATUS,
                                            NOTES,
                                            CREATED_BY,
                                            CREATED_ON,
                                            UPDATE_BY,
                                            UPDATE_ON)
                                            VALUES
                                            (ORDER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,      --ORDER_ID
                                            :TB_INVOICE_ID,    --CUSTOMER_ID
                                            :DGV_PRODUCT_DESC,          --PRODUCT_ID
                                            :DGV_QUANTITY,              --QUANTITY
                                            :DGV_UNIT_PRICE,            --UNIT_PRICE
                                            NULL,                       --ORDER_STATUS
                                            :DGV_NOTES,                 --NOTES
                                            'SYSTEM',                   --CREATED_BY
                                            SYSDATE,                    --CREATED_ON
                                            NULL,                       --UPDATE_BY
                                            NULL)                       --UPDATE_ON
                        RETURNING ORDER_ID INTO :OUT_ORDER_ID";   //~ Returning VAULES ~//

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertcmdtxt, conn))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = seqcmdtxt;

        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = reader["CUSTSEQ"].ToString();
        }
        cmd.CommandText = insertcmdtxt;



        for (int i = 0; i < DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //~ refreshing parameters ~//
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TB_INVOICE_ID", TB_INVOICE_ID.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DGV_PRODUCT_DESC", DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DGV_QUANTITY", DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DGV_UNIT_PRICE", DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DGV_NOTES", DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));

            cmd.Parameters.Add(":OUT_ORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(":OUT_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":OUT_ORDER_ID"].Value).ToString();
        //TB_NOTES.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":OUT_CUSTOMER_ID"].Value).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    { MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "error msg", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
}
```

Comment: With databases, you cannot really control the order the data is stored because it is controlled internally inside the database to optimize storage.  So when output data from a database you should always add an "Order By" statement so your output are in the order you want like by ID or by Date.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers.

- Consider separating the code that gets the Customer ID from code that adds the invoice rows

  int GetCustomerId();

  void AddInvoice(int customerId);
- You seem to be storing the CUSTSEQ in, what looks like, a global variable (input box). I would considering storing that in a local variable

  string customerSequenceId = reader["CUSTSEQ"].ToString(); 
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TB_INVOICE_ID", customerSequenceId));

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't need to be too concerned with the order in which records in the database are stored. (It makes some difference with regard to performance, but from the perspective of your application it doesn't matter.) What matters is the order in which records are sorted *when you retrieve them*. And that can vary. In one scenario you might want them ordered by date, in another by quantity, etc.

So what matters first is your 'ORDER BY' clause in your SQL query. Even though a database might appear to return records in some predictable sequence, it's important to always specify the order unless it absolutely doesn't matter.

Then if you build collections like `List<Order>` from the results of that query in your application you'll want to also ensure that if the sequence matters, you also specify an `.OrderBy` or `.OrderByDescending` in your LINQ expressions. Many operations, like `.Select`, will always return records in their original sequence, so if you know the sort order when you start you don't need to specify it again and again with every operation. But if you're selecting distinct groups or joining, or passing collections from one function to another so that the order may be uncertain, then you may need to sort them again *if the sort order matters.*